# How Updating a Record's Parent Affects a Before Trigger That Pulls Data From Parent's Fields

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Before Insert, Before Update trigger on a custom object, Financial Account, that is a child in a master-detail relationship with Account. When the Financial Account is updated/inserted, the trigger pulls the lookup field 'Portfolio Manager' from the account, and updates the 'Portfolio Manager' lookup field on the Financial Account.

If the field changed on Financial Account (which allows re-parenting) is the Account that it is linked to, will the 'Portfolio Manager' field on Financial Account be pulled from the *old* Account that it is linked to, or the *new* Account that it is *being* linked to?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added relevant code.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger transferRelationshipTeamFromAcctOnFinAcctUpdate on Financial_Account__c (before insert, before update) {
    FinancialAccountManager.handleUpdateTransferRelationshipTeamFromAcct(trigger.new);
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class FinancialAccountManager {
public static void handleUpdateTransferRelationshipTeamFromAcct(List<Financial_Account__c> FinAcctsTrNew){
    Set<Id> clients = new Set<Id>{};
    for(Financial_Account__c finAcct : finAcctsTrNew){
        //Compile a set of all clients from all FinAccts in Trigger.new
        clients.add(finAcct.client__c);
    }

    //Get the client's fields
    Map<Id, Account> clientsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
        SELECT Id, Wealth_Advisor__c, Portfolio_Manager_Lookup__c,Trust_Officer__c, Other_Team_Member_1__c, Other_Team_Member_2__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN :clients]);

    //Loop through each Financil Account
    for(Financial_Account__c finAcct : FinAcctsTrNew){
        //Update the Relationship Teams on the Financial Account from the Parent Account
        finAcct.Wealth_Advisor_Lookup__c = clientsMap.get(finAcct.client__c).Wealth_Advisor__c;

        finAcct.Portfolio_Manager_Lookup__c = clientsMap.get(finAcct.client__c).Portfolio_Manager_Lookup__c;

        finAcct.Trust_Officer_Lookup__c = clientsMap.get(finAcct.client__c).Trust_Officer__c;

        finAcct.Other_Team_Member_1_Lookup__c = clientsMap.get(finAcct.client__c).Other_Team_Member_1__c;

        finAcct.Other_Team_Member_2_Lookup__c = clientsMap.get(finAcct.client__c).Other_Team_Member_2__c;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the account lookup from the `Trigger.New`, You should be getting the financial account from the new parent on a before update.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I fully understood your answer, so I added the code I was referring to. Would you mind checking it out and letting me know if you think it would work correctly, meaning that if the Financial Accounts parent was changed, the Financial Account's Relationship Team fields would correctly populate based on the *new* parent Account. Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to test what you said in my sandbox and you were right, thanks again!

Comment: Code looks fine. Though, I'd go for a more general method name, as this is not only ran at re-parenting of your child records(which is somewhat implied with 'transferRelationship'. Also runs at the initial parenting (before insert).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the tip, but I think my meaning got lost in translation. It wasn't supposed to be 'Transfer Relationship', it's supposed to be 'Transfer Relationship Team from Account'.

Comment: Oh right. I should have picked that up from the comment though.